# Inputting a set of numbers then outputting a specific number? In R

Tags: r

Basically I need to enter a set of numbers in and the criterions are to enter in more than three numbers and what I input needs to be a number and not a letter. If either one of these criteria fails there needs to be an error message. I have attempted two ways of going about it. One way is probably easier but none-the-less I cannot get either of them to run.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
NUM <- function(){
message("ENTER THREE NUMBERS!")          
pre>  x <- as.vector(readLines(n = 3))              

 while (x = is.numeric){                
  message("ERROR\nPLEASE ENTER THREE NUMBERS!")
   x <- is.vector(readLines(n = 3))
   }

 if(x(1) > x(3) && x(2) > x(3))           
  print(x(3))<P>

 if(x(1) > x(3) && x(2) < x(3))<P>
  print(x(2))<P>

if(x(1) < x(3) && x(2) > x(1))<b>
  print(x(1))
}
NUM()
```

The code above repeats for some reason even through entering actual numbers.

```
NUM3 <- function(x){  
message("ENTER THREE NUMBERS!")      ###user input of 3 numbers###
        x <- is.vector(readLines(n = 3))  ### telling input is a vector####

       while (x != TRUE){                
          message("ERROR\nPLEASE ENTER THREE NUMBERS!")              
          x <- is.vector(readLines(n = 3))
       }
 BOB <- sort(x)      ###sorting the three numbers### 
 print(BOB(3))      ###then printing the 3rd number###
}
NUM3()
```

This code seems to be the way to go and prefer to use it but again I cannot get it to run.

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I am new to R coding and coding in general.

Best

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the following code,

`x <- is.vector(readLines(n = 3))`

your input is being created as a character vector:

To give you an example:

```
> num <- function(x) {
+     message("Enter Three Numbers!")
+     x <- is.vector(readLines(n = 3))
+     print(x)
+ }

> num()
Enter Three Numbers!
2
7
4
[1] "2" "7" "4"
```

I hope this helps.